# UINavigationBarAppearance not layout on the first time on the controller on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, ios13

I’m new so I hope that’s the way things goes around here !

Like y’all know, iOS 13 introduced UI changes. We have an app in production and I recently woke up (maybe a little too late haha) and as I compiled and launch it on a freshly updated iOS 13 device, that’s when I became aware there was some work to do ! I handled the dark mode by not enabling it, I handled my modals but there is one thing I can’t seem to make like iOS 12 and it’s my Navigation Bar UI.

We use a custom back button image and after fighting during several hours, I finally succeeded but it’s ok everytime except the first time. I will always have the default icon the first time, and then when I come back to the same controller, it’s okay. The function I use is called in viewWillAppear.

Here is my code ! I know it’s possible to use Appearance for specific VC with « whenContained » but I can’t seem to figure it out cause it’s all in navigation controller and I don’t know how to differentiate them.

```swift
fileprivate func navigationBarWithBackgroundColor(_ backgroundColor: UIColor, TintColor tintColor: UIColor, displayBackButtonIfNeeded: Bool, BackImage imageName:String, displayShadowBar: Bool = false) {

let backButtonImage = UIImage(named: imageName)

if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {

    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.backgroundColor = backgroundColor

    appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: tintColor]
    appearance.setBackIndicatorImage(backButtonImage, transitionMaskImage: backButtonImage)
    appearance.shadowImage = displayShadowBar ? UIImage(named:"") : UIImage()

    let back = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
    // hide back button text
    back.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]
    appearance.backButtonAppearance = back

    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
    navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance

} else {
    if displayBackButtonIfNeeded {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backButtonImage
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backButtonImage
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    } else {
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    }

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = backgroundColor
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:""), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = displayShadowBar ? UIImage(named:"") : UIImage()
}
```

I’m basically become crazy here and I assume I’m missing something very obvious so if you guys have any hints or clues except apple documentation, feel free to share :) Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?
I have the same issue, for now I call `navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()` after setting everything. But I'm not a fan of it.